# How to represent Empty Set?

Tags: c#, math, data-structures, set, set-theory

From set theory:

> Sets A,B are disjoint exactly if A∩B = {}

*where {} is empty set*.

Reference: [**Elementary Set Theory with a Universal Set**, *by Randall Holmes*](http://www.e-booksdirectory.com/details.php?ebook=5313)

Furthermore it says;

> It is not correct to say that disjoint sets A and B have “no intersection”; they do have an intersection, namely the empty set, but this intersection has no elements

Also if A and B are disjoint, then `A∩B = B∩A = {}`

In C#:

```
using System.Linq;
...
...

HashSet<string> a = new HashSet<string>(new[] { "a", "b" });
HashSet<string> b = new HashSet<string>(new[] { "d", "c" });

a.Intersect(b) == b.Intersect(a); // => false
```

Why?

If `==` is just comparing the Id of the object (instead; if `a` is `b`; not the `is` operator of C#), is there any way to represent actual `Empty Set`?

Comment: It seems like the issue is not how to represent the empty set (or any other set in particular), but how to compare sets in general. Also note that intersection is commutative, meaning `A∩B = B∩A` for any two sets A, B.

Comment: `bool empty = !a.Intersect(b).Any()`

Comment: @delnan, you are right; the `Interest()` method should return an instance of `HashSet<T>()` with no elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `Intersect` returns `IEnumerable<string>`. Therefore you are comparing two *instances* of IEnumerable. As L.B mentioned in the comments, you can use `Any` to check whether the resultant `IEnumerable<string>` is empty.

```
bool empty = !a.Intersect(b).Any();
```

Another way would be to use HashSet's `SetEquals` method.

```
var ab = new HashSet<string>(a.Intersect(b));

bool equal = ab.SetEquals(b.Intersect(a));
```

Comment: Thanks. `.SetEquals()` is the way to go!

Answer (score 0):

The `==` operator in C# and most similar programming languages is not the kind of equality that you can find in mathematics. It behaves like that with most numbers, but even that is not always true (in case of floating point rounding errors). It is very different when it comes to comparing objects. In your case, it merely compares whether the two object instances are exactly the same or not (see `Object.ReferenceEquals`), and clearly they aren't the same. A `new HashSet<string>()` represents an empty set, but if you type it twice, they will be two different object instances. You can define your own custom equality operator if you like (see operator overloading).